# Send mail from ASP.Net that automatically saves to client's Outlook calendar

Tags: asp.net, outlook

I just want to send a reminder mail from my ASP.Net application to Outlook that automatically saves to the targeted Outlook Emailid calandar.

I have implemented this, but this is working on my system's Outlook only. It doesn't work on other systems.

```
protected void btSent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { SendMail("xyz@xyz.com", "xyx"); } public void SendMail(string targetMail, string shownTargetName) { MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("xyz@xyz.com", "MailSendingProgram"); MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(targetMail, shownTargetName); String fromPassword = "xyz"; String subject = "Test Recurrence"; String body = @" Here you can put in any text that will appear in the body multilined and even in "; SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient { Host = "smtp.xyz.com", Port = 25, EnableSsl = true, DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network, UseDefaultCredentials = false, Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword) };

    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    }
          )
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                 { return true; };
            smtp.Send(message);
            lbError.Text = "E-Mail sent!";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application olApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            CreateNewRecurringAppointment(olApp);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(olApp);

        }
        catch
        {
            lbError.Text = "Sending failed, check your internet connection!";
        }
    }
}

public void CreateNewRecurringAppointment(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application OutlookApp) { Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem appItem = null; Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RecurrencePattern pattern = null; try { appItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem; // create a recurrence pattern = appItem.GetRecurrencePattern(); pattern.RecurrenceType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRecurrenceType.olRecursWeekly; pattern.StartTime = DateTime.Parse("8:35:00 AM"); pattern.EndTime = DateTime.Parse("9:35:00 PM"); // we can specify the duration instead of using the EndTime property pattern.Duration = 60; pattern.PatternStartDate = DateTime.Parse("03/9/2015"); pattern.PatternEndDate = DateTime.Parse("03/9/2015"); appItem.Subject = "Meeting with the Boss"; appItem.Body = "Test Appointment body"; appItem.Location = "P1"; appItem.ReminderSet = true; appItem.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15; appItem.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; appItem.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy; appItem.Save(); appItem.Send();

        //appItem.Display(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lbRecur.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (pattern != null)
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pattern);
        }
        if (appItem != null)
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: Welcome! I have taken the code that you put in the "answer" section, and edited it into your question, where it belongs. You could further improve your question by telling us how your code doesn't work - is there anything in the logs? Do you have the appropriate authorizations on the client machines? This kind of information can help us to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) article.

Consider using EWS (Exchange Web Services) or standard classes from BCLs (Base Class Libraries). You may find the [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: but dear the thing is that If you see my code its works but for my system only if i am sending mail to my outlook email-id then it work as per my expectation  but when i am sending that mail to some other email not on my system it won't works it was not added automatically....... this is issue